# Insert an element at a specific position in an Array using pointers in C++

Tags: c++

I need help in inserting the an element in an array using pointers at a specific position. I have try to solve with the following method but it is not working. I would be pleased to share my code with you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int* add( int a[] , int );
int main()
{

    int size = NULL;
    cout<<"Enter the size of the array: ";
    cin>>size;
    
    int a[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
       cin>> a[i];
    }
    add(a , size);
    return 0;
}
    
int* add( int a[] , int size )
{
    int *p = NULL , *q = NULL , *r = NULL;

    p = a;
    q = p;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
       cout<<*p<<" ";
       p +=1;
    }

    p = q;

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) // loop for  moving the pointer to the last of the array
    {
        p++;
    }    
    p--;

    cout<<endl<<*p<<endl;

    r = p; // storing the address of last element of the array

}
```

Comment: You cannot insert anything in C-style array. The size of an array is fixed. You could pretend that you are inserting something by making a much bigger array and keeping last elements unused, but that's it.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a vector and leveraging `std::vector<T>::insert`?

Comment: It's not even c++ as c++ does not support variable length arrays

Comment: the comments above aside, it is not clear where in your code you think you are inserting something to the array. You pass `size` to `add` but you only use it to iterate already existing elements. I don't understand your `add`. Can you explain what it is supposed to do?

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) p++;` can be improved to `p += size;`. Incl. the `p = q;` before and the `p--;` afterwards, it would be `p = q + size - 1;`.

Comment: btw don't do this `int size = NULL;`. It is only coincidence that this is not an error. You should be using `nullptr` instead of `NULL`, and `nullptr` is not an `int`.

Comment: Use std::vector instead of array

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cin>>size;
>
> int a[size];
> ```

The size of an array variable must be compile time constant in C++. `size` is not compile time constant. The program is ill-formed. If you need an array with dynamic size, then you need to allocate the array dynamically. Simplest way to do that is to use `std::vector`.

---

The function `add` is declared to return `int*` but there is no return statement. The behaviour of the program is undefined. This can be solved by returning a value.

---

> Insert an element at a specific position in an Array

First, shift the elements on the right side of the specific position - including the element in the position - one index to right. Then assign the specific position with the new value. Since the size of an array never changes, the last element cannot be shifted and its value will be overwritten.